# cannot connect another sql server instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

i have active directory, both sql server db01 and db02 are joined in domain and setup default all.

i'm trying to connect another sql server instance db02 from db01 sql server

file->connect

Server Type: Database Engine

Server Name (i tried IP address or FQDN but it's still not working)

Authentication: Windows Authentication

Domain\Administrator

When i click connect button it says

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwRO9.png)

i also tried enabling the sa account and setting password, can't also connect

i tried firewall off on both db01 and 02, still the same issue.

all services for sql is running, and network tcp and pipename are enabled.

remote connection is set to enable/allow

did i miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message tells you correctly that the problem is around authentication.

Either you are using a non-Windows application to connect to the the SQL server instances OR you are logged with your normal account BUT you are trying to authenticate as Domain\Administrator. Windows authentication will mostly not let you do that.

A problem with some non-Windows tools is that they let you *try* to connect using Windows Authentication and typing in a username, but it will never work. Instead, to use windows authentication you have to login to Windows as Domain\Administrator OR run your Application as Domain\Administrator, using e.g. right-click 'Run as other user'

To connect from a non-Windows platform using windows authentication depends entirely on your application and driver having correctly implemented it.